# Where can I find statistics on average feerates at different times of day and days of the week?

Tags: transaction-fees, statistics

I know there are websites that show the price needed to get a tx into a block if made now, but is there any website that show the average price per byte for a tx at different times of the week and day? I am pretty sure there will be daily and weekly patterns, so it would be cool to see this if someone has collected this data.

If not, I guess I'll have to create this myself! Thanks for any URLs or tips.

Comment: I've reopened this question, because it's not clear to me how it was soliciting reviews or asking for a product recommendation. Rebroad appears to be looking for a specific type of statistic which is a request that can be objectively answered from publicly available information. I also edited the title slightly to clarify the problem that the asker appears to be trying to solve.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103720/5406

Comment: I just saw the graphs in this wiki article today, which you might find interesting: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Miner_fees

Answer (score 1):

As someone keenly interested in that sort of stuff, I'm not aware of a website that shows the weekly and daily patterns in feerates.

The closest thing I could find was this chart that compares the feerate ranges of blocks on [Bitcoin Optech Dashboard](https://dashboard.bitcoinops.org/d/4Pm4uKFmk/fee-rate-comparion).

I was unable to find a graph that matches your description more closely across dashboard.bitcoinops.org, statoshi.info, transactionfee.info, bitinfocharts.com, blockchair.com, and txstats.com. You could perhaps build something like that on Coinmetrics.io, but the feerate is not one of the metrics they share publicly. Some of these projects may welcome your suggestion.

If you do build it, please add an answer here to point it out when you have! I would definitely want to see it!

Comment: I'm currently modifying bitcoind to log the necessary numbers (e.g. lowest fee/vB/TX per block and highest fee/vB/TX in the mempool right after receiving a block)

Not quite sure what algorithm to use to find the right number between those two values yet is though...

Comment: Note that you may want to collect the lowest "effective" feerate. E.g. in the case of child pays for parent, a transaction may have a much lower individual feerate, but its effective feerate was higher due to the high fee the child paid. Otherwise, you could perhaps use percentiles like https://twitter.com/BitcoinConfs

Comment: hmmm.. do you know if code already exists that does the job of finding all children, granchildren, etc of a tx - so that I can calculate the total size of the whole family, and total fees?

Comment: Inputs use the txid to identify the outputs they spend, so you can just get it from the transactions directly. You can also get it via RPC calls on Bitcoin Core: [`getmempooldescendants`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getmempooldescendants.html), [`getmempoolancestors`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getmempoolancestors.html)